# How to avoid Class Library direct linkage with the main assembly?

Tags: c#, dll, plugins, .net-assembly

I'm trying to have a Class Library implement interfaces from a main assembly in a plugin system fashion. I currently have a working setup where I reference the main assembly in the class library and implement the interfaces there. I then load instances through reflection. I would like to avoid the new class libraries to have hard references to the main application.

From a C++ standpoint, I would only provide header files to be implemented by the library. Then some dynamic loading would occur and make the new binary implementation available to the main application. It seems that there is no concept of "providing a header file" in C#.

It seems very weird that the class library needs a hard reference on the main app just to inherit an interface. It also brings other concerns which are currently of lesser immediate importance, like sealing classes or managing internal classes visibility.

Solution 2 would be to create another layer of indirection through a new class library and expose interfaces there only. This sounds like a lot of work just to provide a few interface classes to new libraries.

Are there other options available?

EDIT:

Current setup:

I have 2 projects in my solution. One is a console app (MyApp) and the other is a class library (ExtensionDll). In MyApp, I have an interface like this:

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public interface IPlugin
    {
        void ExecuteThirdPartyCode();
    }
}
```

In ExtensionDll I have

```
namespace ExtensionDll
{
    class ThirdPartyExtension : MyApp.IPlugin
    {
        void ExecuteThirdPartyCode()
        {
            //Their secret sauce
        }
    }
}
```

In MyApp, I can then load this with

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(ExtensionDllPath);
```

find classes implementing IPlugin and call `ExecuteThirdPartyCode()` on them.

Comment: The header file is the "using" (the reference libraries) statement in c# at the top of each module.  The library is a dll and public objects are available to other classes.  You do not need hard references, you can reference the public objects in the libraries (namespaces).

Comment: Ok, so how can I have a "using" statement without an underlying reference? Or is adding references like this the usual way of doing things?

Comment: If you use the Solution explorer you will see a list of reference libraries.  For each reference library you need one or more (a reference may have multiple namespaces) using statements at the top of the module.  A using statement is required for each namespace.  if you do not have a reference than you need to use a DLLIMPORT definition.

Comment: I have updated my question. I already figured out how to add references to projects. As a matter of fact, this is what I would currently want to avoid. By referencing MyApp directly, it forces every 3rd party developer to have a copy of MyApp whenever they're compiling.

I'll probably create a new class library with shared definitions instead as I don't see any better option

Comment: If you want other developers to use your package, consider distributing it via NuGet, this is the defacto package manager for C#.

Comment: Put the plugin interfaces into a separate assembly which is then referenced from both your main assembly and the plugin implementation assemblies.